# Prove an inequality satisfied eventually by Taylor

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, taylor-expansion

In order to try to answer by myself to this [My related previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4134885/900585), since it has no answer (if someone can help me I am very grateful) I want to clarify this doubts:
if I have to prove that a certain inequality is satisfied eventually as $x\to 0$ can I use the Mcalurin expansion?
I mean if I want to search for $a$ and $b$ such that

> $f(ax)<g(bx)$ eventually as $x\to0$

is it sufficient to impose that $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(ax)-g(ax)\leq 0$$ and from this I find out the right parametres $a$ and $b$? I am not sure above all of the fact that the limit is $\leq 0$ and not $<0$.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why not a strict inequality? What is your logic for that?

Comment: A strict equality surely will be correct, but also the limit zero gives me the possibility to prove the inequality?

Comment: Above all I think to include also $=$ since in the inequality of my previuso question I think that $s=1$ must be included...but I am not sure

Comment: Read my answer please, and revert back. Can you find any wrong argument?

Comment: Do you mean that the inequality must be strict?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm getting. It's logical too. Suppose you consider two functions, x=0 and a piece wise defined function such that it's value is zero in the vicinity of origin, then if you don't use a strict inequality it would become an acceptable solution, even though it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you want is:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(ax)<\lim_{x\to 0}g(bx)$$
Using algebra of limits, you can bring RHS to LHS as:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(ax)-g(bx))<0$$
Now you can evaluate this limit however you want, including using McLaurin series.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you help me also in solving https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4134885/900585?

Comment: You're welcome. If the solution is correct, you can "accept" it and close the question.

Comment: What's happen in your opinion when $s=1$?

Comment: It depends upon the value of k. Exactly at x=0, the functions are equal, and that is enough for your question. If you really want to get an insight, draw a plot on desmos. That will help

Comment: The limit is $0$ in case $s=1$, can I say that $\sin{x}-e^{x/(1-x)}+\cos{x}<0$?