# Prove that eventually $f(x)\leq 0$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, solution-verification

If I want to prove that $f(x)\leq 0$ eventually as $x\to 0$ is sufficient that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\leq 0$, using so the theorem of permanence of sign?
For the strict equality I know that it is true but in case of $\leq$ I am not sure

Comment: To clarify, you want to show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) \le 0$ implies $f(x) \le 0$ eventually as $x\to 0$?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Yes!

Comment: It can easily happen that $f(x)\lt0$ for all $x$ near $0$ but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ *does not exist* (in which case the inequality $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\le0$ doesn't really make sense). Are you restricting to functions for which the limit does exist?

Comment: @BarryCipra yes the limit of the function exist. In particular I am trying to understand the values of $k$ and $s$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4134885/900585.  I suspect that also $s=1$ is good

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(x)=|x|$ is always positive for $x\ne 0$, even though $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\leq 0$.

Comment: Ok thanks but the implication for strict inequality is right? I mean https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4135218/900585

Comment: @cely For strict inequality yes.

Comment: If the limit is $\leq 0$ itcan be possible that $f(x)<0$?

Comment: Yes, take $f(x)=-|x|$.

Comment: So to sum up: I can say that if $\lim_{x\to}f(x)\leq 0$ then $f(x)<0$?

Comment: No, my answer shows that it is not always the case. Sometimes it is the case, but not always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124145/discussion-between-cely-and-mark).

Comment: You got an answer to that question, you need to use strict inequality. This is also what I wrote in my answer (and comments) here.

Comment: Ok but if $s=1$ what happens?